# How can i get a certain amount of JSON data from an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js

pretty new programmer here, hopefully, this isn't too much of a rudimentary question, just couldn't find the answer anywhere (maybe I just don't know how to look?).

I'm currently working with the BandsInTown API and everything is working great, aside from the fact that I'm receiving way more objects than I need.

I would just like to know if there is a way that I can specify a certain number of objects that I want to receive back?
Any help is appreciated.

```js
require("dotenv").config();

var keys = require("./keys.js");
var request = require('request')
var moment = require('moment')
var media = process.argv.slice(3).join(" ")



function bandsFunct() {
    var artist = "";
    for (var i = 3; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
        if (i !== 3) artist += "-"
        artist += process.argv[i];
    }
    if (process.argv[2] == "concert-this")
        request("https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/" + artist + "/events?app_id=codingbootcamp", function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(response.body)
            var body = JSON.parse(body)
            console.log("    ")
            console.log("-------------------------------------")
            console.log("    ")
            console.log("Upcoming concerts for " + artist + ": ");
            for(var set in body) {
                var date = moment(body[set].datetime).format("MM/DD/YYYY")
                console.log(body[set].venue.city + ", " + "at " + body[set].venue.name + ", " + "on " + date) 
            }
            console.log("    ")
            console.log("-------------------------------------")
            console.log("    ")
        })
}
bandsFunct();
```

Comment: The best way to find what you need is to read the documentation https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/Bandsintown/PublicAPI/3.0.0#/artist%20events/artistEvents *Hint*: There's a `date` query param that you can use to specify range

Answer (score -1):

> suppose you  have a object

```
let obj = { 
         { name: 'war', class :'12' , age: 21, field: 'cse' } ,
          { name: 'jar', class :'120' , age: 251, field: 'csee' }
       }
```

> if you want  some selected fields you can do like this

```
 var result = Object.keys(obj).filter(item => 

  item.class < 100 // you can specify any condition
  )

 // the result will contain only those objects whose class < 100
```